# How do I target a specific index number for a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, iteration

How do I target a specific index number for a function? Or how would I target every 9th image (assuming there will be hundreds).

https://jsfiddle.net/nightcoregirl/2z0qgp1g/24/

```
var basicCount = function(){

    $('.photo').each(function(index){
        index++; 
        $this = $(this);
        $this.append('<div class="number">' + index + '</div>')
    });

}

    basicCount();
```

This is what I got for just displaying index number... I don't understand iteration much at this point.

Comment: Depending on how your HTML is structured you can simply use :nth-child(9) tag. Worst case scenario that index variable out and have if statement that says if(index == 9){} ... PS you need to define that index as 
var index = 0 or var index;;

Comment: Try **[:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)** selector jQuery. `$('.photo:nth-child(9n)')`

Comment: But I don't want to target only the 9th div I want to target every increment of 9. 9th, 18th, 27th, 36th, 45th etc.... Does what you say still apply?

Comment: Yes. *9n* applies to every 9th element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.photo').each(function(index){
    if(index%8==0)
    {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.append('<div class="number">' + index + '</div>')
    }
});
```

Comment: He want to target every 9th image, nut just 9th image.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nth-child` selector:

```
$('.photo:nth-child(9n)').append('<div class="number">' + index + '</div>');
```

This would be target **every 9th image**.

**Update:**

```
index = $(this).index + 1;
$('.photo:nth-child(9n)').append('<div class="number">' + index + '</div>');
```

Comment: Interesting.. trying this for the 3rd image. It worked but it stacks all of the total index length, not the specific index number.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "%" or modular function to determine every 9th item

First of all, no need to handle a count variable on your own, the .each() function already supplies an index element (as an optional argument).

With the modulus operator you can get the remainder from dividing the index by 3. Then you can tell when do you need to print the opening of the row and the ending of it.

```
$(data).find('products').each(function(index) {

    itemName = $(this).find('itemName').text();
    itemDesc = $(this).find('itemDesc').text();
    itemID = $(this).find('id').text();

        if ((index % 3) == 0) items += '<div class="row-fluid">';

        items += '<div class="span3">Col 1</div>';

        if ((index % 3) == 2) items += '</div>';
});

if (items.substr(-12) != '</div></div>') items += '</div>';
```

That is just an example, you can try to apply it to your own code